# What exactly is a formatting context?

Tags: css

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flow_Layout/Intro_to_formatting_contexts):

> Everything on a page is part of a **formatting context**, or an area which has been defined to lay out content in a particular way.

So, according to MDN, *formatting context* is an **area**. But it's not clear what they mean by "area". What does "area" mean here?

Also from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Block_formatting_context):

> A **block formatting context** is a part of a visual CSS rendering of a web page. It's the region in which the layout of block boxes occurs and in which floats interact with other elements.

What does being a part of a visual CSS rendering of a web page for an element mean here? It says, it's a **region**, coinciding with **area** from the above excerpt. Then it says, *BFC* is a region—I suppose, they mean a visual region or area of the viewport—where the layout (the visual organization of html elements) happens.

"An element *establishes* a formatting context" is a very common phrase used throughout many CSS tutorials. `display: flow-root` establishes a BFC.

```css
.box {
  background-color: #ddd;
  padding: 1em;
}

.box-1 {
  background-color: brown;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
}

.box-2 {
  background-color: cadetblue;
  width: 7em;
  height: 7em;
}

.para {
  background-color: yellowgreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="box-1"></div>

  <p class="para">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Velit aliquam nisi necessitatibus consequuntur ducimus dolor maxime cumque repellat? Explicabo dolore deleniti aut sequi assumenda dolor ex deserunt, blanditiis itaque eum.
  </p>

  <div class="box-2"></div>
</div>
```

Here, the `.box` element, along with all its contents, is a part of the **initial block formatting context**—this is what MDN and other tutorials say. Now, if I add the CSS declaration `display: flow-root` to `.box`, the `.box` element will establish a new BFC and then all of its contents will be parts of that newly established BFC, or will *participate* in that BFC. And, since, according to MDN, BFC is an area or a region of the viewport where the layout "lives" (occurs), the viewport region—perhaps the area of the padding box of the element—that the `.box` parent element occupies must be the BFC it establishes.

Am I right? Could you make it more clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A formatting context is not really an area. It's more a *state* of a box that defines the set of layout rules that apply to itself and its participant boxes.

Comment: hi @alohci, maybe you can help here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68544990/8620333 there is some confusion there and the accepted answer is probably not accurate (I suspect it's related to the overflow propagation but not sure how it's related to the JS value). Thanks

Comment: @TemaniAfif - Agreed on the propagation, but I couldn't establish a complete spec trail. The JS value is the border box width of the root element, which sits inside the initial containing block, which is defined of having the dimensions of the viewport. But the definition of the viewport in 2.2 doesn't say whether its scrollbars should be included in its dimensions or not.