# Why does offsetWidth show incorrect value?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I wrote this code.

When I added scroll-bar, I got 403 as clientWidth, and this seems like true: 403px for inner content + 17px for scroll-bar. And then I got 403 as offsetWidth, but offsetWidth must include scroll-bar width. Therefore I should get 403+17, not 403.

Why do I get 403 as result in (*)?

```js
let html = document.documentElement
console.log(window.innerWidth) // 420 on my test
console.log(html.clientWidth) // 420
console.log(html.offsetWidth) // 420

html.style.overflowY = 'scroll' // add scroll-bar
console.log('Window: ' + window.innerWidth) // Window: 420
console.log('clientWidth: ' + html.clientWidth) // clientWidth: 403
console.log('offsetWidth: ' + html.offsetWidth) // offsetWidth: 403 (*)
```

Comment: Maybe on the document element it doesn’t include the scroll bar?

Comment: I made a snippet and changed one 403 to 420

Comment: What browsers have you tested this in? They all render the same value in Mac Firefox.

Comment: I used Google Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>You almost got us! But there it is...</sub>

Take a closer look at the [`documentElement`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/documentElement).

[image: Layout of documentElement]

The scrollbar is not included! Therefore the only way to get the site width **including** scrollbars is [`window.innerWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window/innerWidth).

> The read-only [Window](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window) property [`innerWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window/innerWidth) returns the interior width of the window in pixels. This includes the width of the vertical scroll bar, if one is present.

<sup><s>The value of [`offsetWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) will include scrollbars for all [elements](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Element) except the [`documentElement`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/documentElement).</s></sup>
[`offsetWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) of [`documentElement`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/documentElement) includes scrollbars, but it simply doesn't have any. Which means that [`offsetWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth) and [`clientWidth`](//dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Element/clientWidth) are the same.

Comment: Thanks, bro! You helped me a lot.

Comment: I must say I didn't know this either. So thank you too! If you wonder where I got the image, you can [inspect](https://dev.mozilla.org/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools#the_inspector_dom_explorer_and_css_editor "MDN Web Docs") everything yourself!

Comment: I don't see where in your links or quote it is said that `offsetWidth` should not take the vertical scrollbar into account for `document.documentElement`. There is a special case for this documentElement (or body in Quirks mode) in the specs for `clientWidth`, where they state it should match the viewport's width minus the scrollbar, but I can't see anything in `offsetWidth`. Could you pin-point and quote exactly where it is said it should behave like this? Currently your answer is just stating what the question was already stating. The question is *Why* does it behaves like that.

Comment: For sure, you can read about this at [Windows sizes and scrolling](https://javascript.info/size-and-scroll-window#width-height-of-the-window "JavaScript.info"). They don't mention [`offsetWidth`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth "MDN Web Docs") but simply teach to use [`window.innerWidth`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Window/innerWidth "MDN Web Docs") for this case. The question is **not** *why* it *behaves* like that, but *why* the value is *incorrect*. And the value is correct. The scrollbar is not placed on the `documentElement`, but on the `window`.

Comment: How can you know the value is correct? Where is it said that the scrollbar should not be placed on the `documentElement`? Because you see this value doesn't mean that it is correct. Unless you can show where in the specification it is said that the scrollbar should not be part of the `documentElement` (and I'm pretty sure there is somewhere this can be derived from), we can only assume that `documentElement` should be treated as any other element, i.e, with the scrollbar being part of its `offsetWidth`.

Comment: I can't currently find any official source mentioning this topic. If you wish, you can edit the answer and include one. Otherwise I think I presented a very **trustful** source ([Developer Tools](https://dev.mozilla.org/docs/Glossary/Developer_Tools "MDN Web Docs")) so we don't have to *assume that [`documentElement`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/documentElement "MDN Web Docs") should be treated as any other element* as it **shouldn't**. If you don't believe hit `Ctrl + Shift + I` and test yourself. I can't help you any more.

Comment: No this is not a "trustful" source at all. The DevTools do show exactly the result of `offsetWidth`. So if the browser gets `offsetWidth` wrong, the dev-tools will also have it wrong. And no, if I take the time to find exactly what's going on I won't edit your answer which once again doesn't bring anything to the question, I would rather post a new answer. But I don't have the time nor the will to do that research. It is now your responsibility as an answerer to provide the correct answer, backed with correct sources.

Comment: I see what's the problem... I'm going to fix it in the answer: The [`offsetWidth`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetWidth "MDN Web Docs") of [`documentElement`](https://dev.mozilla.org/Web/API/Document/documentElement "MDN Web Docs") **includes** scrollbars. So it is the **same** as any other element. But `documentElement` does not have **any** scrollbars. Which means the `offsetWidth` will be the same as `clientWidth`. Here Developer Tools **are** a trustful source as they show that the scrollbar is not a part of `documentElement`.

Comment: No it's not a trustful source, once again, they do use the values returned by the various APIs to measure the boxes, so if they have it wrong, the boxes will be wrong too. I suppose the crux lies in [this table](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#scrolling-area), though I'm not sure to understand all the values in there, and moreover I don't see how we fall there from [offsetWidth](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-htmlelement-offsetwidth) for a documentElement (once again, [clientWidth](https://drafts.csswg.org/cssom-view/#dom-element-clientwidth) has a special case for root).

Comment: @Kaiido there is the overflow propagation (https://drafts.csswg.org/css-overflow-3/#overflow-propagation) that play a role here but don't have more accurate information. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68424361/what-exactly-is-a-formatting-context/68425204?noredirect=1#comment121167518_68425204

Comment: @TemaniAfif ah thanks, so if even Alohci can't make the path trough the specs, I won't try harder. Maybe worth a clarification spec issue, but I wonder how implementers were able to reach a "standard" behavior here... Maybe it's just us being able to find the missing link...

Comment: @TemaniAfif Just found [a WPT](https://github.com/web-platform-tests/wpt/blob/master/css/css-overflow/scrollbar-gutter-propagation-003.html) with a comment stating "*Note: as per the spec, the clientWidth of the root element is
"viewport width excluding the size of a rendered scroll bar (if any)"
which does not take scrollbar-gutter into account.
Since no such special case exists for offsetWidth, this means that here
root.clientWidth is greater than root.offsetWidth (!!!).*" So there is indeed a discrepancy at that point between clientWidth and offsetWidth.